# Django lookups that span relationships does not work on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku

For our Django application we have a ManagerProfile that is attached to the Django User model through a OneToOne relationship. For one form we're looking to have a dropdown of managers that belong to a particular company. To do this we use a UserModelMultipleChoiceField that takes a queryset of the managers' User objects.

```
# models.py that holds the ManagerProfile class
class ManagerProfile(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

To create the queryset we do a lookup that queries for Users through the managerprofile relationship (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).

```
# inside get_form_kwargs
self.company = get_object_or_404(Company, pk=kwargs['company_id'])
kwargs['managers'] = User.objects.filter(managerprofile__company=self.company)
```

Our code works everywhere but Heroku where we get...

```
"FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'managerprofile' into field. Choices are:  action_object_actions, actor_actions, address, date_joined, email, emailaddress, first_name, follow, groups, id, is_active, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login, last_name, logentry, management, managers_of, password, socialaccount, target_actions, user_permissions, username"
```

we also tried excluding User objects without ManagerProfiles...

```
kwargs['managers'] = User.objects.exclude(managerprofile__isnull=True).filter(managerprofile__company=self.company)
```

and reorganizing how the queryset is produced...

```
profiles = ManagerProfile.objects.filter(company=self.company)
kwargs['managers'] = User.objects.filter(managerprofile__in=profiles)
```

... but we always end up with the same error.

For some reason the User-ManagerProfile relationship is not recognized when building the queryset but we are able to grab data from the ManagerProfile throughout the rest of the application.

Comment: Seems like the settings file that is being used on Heroku does not contain the app that managerprofile is in.

Comment: That would definitely be a possible cause for this issue but unfortunately a diff between my local and Heroku copy only shows the database settings as being different. The application on Heroku allows me to access information from the managerprofile through a user instance and only breaks when generating a queryset using the User model and filtering on the associated managerprofile...